# jquery 'regex' toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an id of the form id = `MAIN`.  When a button is clicked, I want ALL other id's in the dom of the form (`MAIN_*)` where * is any string to be toggled, so:

```
$(something).toggle(); // will toggle all id's MAIN_*
```

How would I do this in the click event of my button?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(button).click(function(){
  $("#MAIN *[id^=MAIN_]").toggle();
});
```

Comment: maybe im doing something wrong but it doesnt seem to be working.  I need all ides of the form MAIN_... to toggle, but MAIN should not toggle.